# How to fit a multivariate normal distribution in R?

Tags: r, normal-distribution, multivariate-testing, iris-dataset

I need to fit a multivaraite normal distribution to each specie in the Iris dataset in R. I saw the `mvtnorm`package might be useful; however, i want to use the maximum likelihood estimation and not sure how to do so in R. Any ideas?

Comment: Try the `mclust` package.

Comment: I tried that using the code below; however, how do I adjust it to using MLE? `his<-MVN::mvn(data=iris, subset="Species", univariatePlot="histogram")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for a mixture discriminant analysis (since class labels are known). In this case, you can use the `MclustDA` from the `mclust` package.

```
 model= MclustDA(data = iris[,1:4], class = iris$Species)
 summary(model)
```

However, if you are looking to cluster the data using by fitting multivariate Gaussian mixtures then you can use the `Mclust` function.

```
  fit = Mclust(data = iris[,1:4], G=3)
  table(fit$classification, iris$Species)

 #   setosa versicolor virginica
 # 1     50          0         0
 # 2      0         45         0
 # 3      0          5        50
```

Comment: again, how do i ensure that it is fit using the MLE?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/vignettes/mclust.html): "EM algorithm is used by mclust for maximum likelihood estimation."

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to fit a distribution to each species, you might want `mvnorm.mle` in the `Rfast` package:

```
install.packages("Rfast")
library(Rfast)
iris.split <- split(iris[, 1:4], iris$Species)
iris.mvnorm <- lapply(iris.split, function(x) mvnorm.mle(as.matrix(x)))
iris.mvnorm[["setosa"]]
# $loglik
# [1] 44.91657
#
# $mu
# [1] 5.006 3.428 1.462 0.246
#
# $sigma
#              Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# Sepal.Length     0.121764    0.097232     0.016028    0.010124
# Sepal.Width      0.097232    0.140816     0.011464    0.009112
# Petal.Length     0.016028    0.011464     0.029556    0.005948
# Petal.Width      0.010124    0.009112     0.005948    0.010884
```

The other species are stored in `iris.mvnorm[["versicolor"]]` and `iris.mvnorm[["virginica"]]`.